# inserting id where chosen name from drop down menu

Tags: php

i am trying to insert into the database the plan_id where plan_name = (chosen from the select)

can you help me figure out what's wrong in this snippet

```
<?php
$plan_id = ($a);
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_reservation(cust_id, pack_type, plan_id, res_date, res_venue,     date_app) VALUES     ('{$cust_id}','{$pack_type}','{$plan_id}','{$res_date}','{$res_venue}',CURDATE())";
$result_set = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="plan_id">
<?php 
    $queryy = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_wed_plan");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryy)){
    $plan_id = $row['plan_id'];

    echo"<option value='.$row[plan_name].'>$row[plan_name]</option>";
    }

    $a = '';
    if('plan_id' == 'Sho Minamimoto') {
    $a = 'plan-01';
    }else if('plan_id' == 'Janine Tugonon') {
    $a = 'plan-02';
    }else if('plan_id' == 'Jessie Jameson') {
    $a = 'plan-03';
    }else if('plan_id' == 'Karl Marx Bautista') {
    $a = 'plan-04';
    }
?>
```

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ No, it shouldn't be like that. Maybe `$row['plan_id']`?

Comment: Nope, read the code again, `$plan_id` is a defined variable.

Comment: does it give any error ? is the data not getting inserted or the problem is something else ?

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ i changed it it still doesn't insert in the database.

it doesn't insert the values in the database, no errors.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ Maybe, but still `'$plan_id'` isn't a variable, it is string (you put it inside of `'`).

Comment: @ElonThan You are right, it should not be in single quotes

Comment: btw i edited the codes, forgot the select name = plan_id

Comment: @AnnoyedKyo did you echo/print your $plan_id before inserting, just to check what value is coming in it

Comment: @AnnoyedKyo Your insert is outside of php tags, it'll not be executed.

Comment: @ElonThan actually it is inside php tag, that snippet is coming from a mix of html and php.

Comment: If it's inside php tags then `<select name="plan_id">` should cause parse error. Also you're opening `<?php` tag again, it's incorrect too.

Comment: @ElonThan i edited it, since you didn't understand what i meant. :D

Comment: You should provide valid code in first place ;) Check what is returning `mysql_error()` after inserting. Also you can print query to check if all variables are correctly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenation problem.. I guess

```
echo"<option value='".$plan_id."'>".$row[plan_name]."</option>";
```

Comment: ohh yeah you could actually do it like that. what am i thinking. thanks. O: but it still doesn't insert the values in the database, probably something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @AnnoyedKyo You just accepted answer which not solved your problem?

Comment: @ElonThan i tried it on another module, which only inserts plan_id into the table in the database, and it kinda work for me, now i'm having trouble with the other snippets. so he basically just answered what my problem is. O:

Comment: @AnnoyedKyo for the insert problem, did you echo/print your $plan_id before inserting, just to check what value is coming in it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:
user `$plan_id` instead of `'plan_id'`

```
<?php
$plan_id = ($a);
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_reservation(cust_id, pack_type, plan_id, res_date, res_venue,     date_app) VALUES     ('{$cust_id}','{$pack_type}','{$plan_id}','{$res_date}','{$res_venue}',CURDATE())";
$result_set = mysql_query($query);

<?php 
    $queryy = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_wed_plan");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryy)){
    $plan_id = $row['plan_id'];

    echo"<option value='".$plan_id."'>".$row['plan_name']."</option>";
    }

    $a = '';
    if($plan_id == 'Sho Minamimoto') {
    $a = 'plan-01';
    }else if($plan_id == 'Janine Tugonon') {
    $a = 'plan-02';
    }else if($plan_id == 'Jessie Jameson') {
    $a = 'plan-03';
    }else if($plan_id == 'Karl Marx Bautista') {
    $a = 'plan-04';
    }
?>
```

Comment: apparently it shows me these errors

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\wamp\www\itsproj\customer\reservation.php on line 100